# get info and store the info XmlSerialized web page, windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, xml-serialization, windows-phone

I need to be able to do the following:

When the user starts typing, the code goes to this url (XMLSerialized) and then finds all the Stop Name's and then display's them in a auto complete box. Once the user finds the correct one, they then click a button that then goes back to the same URL and then finds the stop id. Then it stores the stop id in a textbox or something for another search (this has been compeleted)

The code format he URL is:

```
<ArrayOfStop xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BusExpress.ClassLibrary" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<Stop z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<EntityKey z:Id="i2" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
<a:EntityContainerName>busExpressEntities</a:EntityContainerName>
<a:EntityKeyValues><a:EntityKeyMember>
<a:Key>stopId</a:Key>
<a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">6400</a:Value>
</a:EntityKeyMember></a:EntityKeyValues>
<a:EntitySetName>StopSet</a:EntitySetName>
</EntityKey>
<AtcoCode>1400WE0400</AtcoCode>
<GPSStopName>Rajdutt Restaurant</GPSStopName>
<Lat>50.952913243742266</Lat><Long>0.11696262657641121</Long>
<LongName>Rajdutt Restaurant</LongName>
<NaptanCode>esudadga</NaptanCode>
<OperatorsCode1>04032</OperatorsCode1>
<OperatorsCode2>4032</OperatorsCode2>
<OperatorsCode3>80414</OperatorsCode3>
<OperatorsCode4>esudadga</OperatorsCode4>
<StopName>Rajdutt Restaurant</StopName>
<route_stop /><route_stop_stop />
<route_stop_timetable_stop /><stopId>6400
</stopId>
</Stop>


<Stop z:Id="i3" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<EntityKey z:Id="i4"   xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
<a:EntityContainerName>busExpressEntities</a:EntityContainerName>
<a:EntityKeyValues><a:EntityKeyMember>
<a:Key>stopId</a:Key>
<a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">6401</a:Value>
/a:EntityKeyMember></a:EntityKeyValues>
<a:EntitySetName>StopSet</a:EntitySetName>
</EntityKey>
<AtcoCode>1400LE10031</AtcoCode>
<GPSStopName>Cysleys Farm</GPSStopName>
<Lat>50.955104287650805</Lat>
<Long>0.11356099694967536</Long>
<LongName>Cysleys Farm</LongName>
<NaptanCode>esudgpgj</NaptanCode>
<OperatorsCode1>04033</OperatorsCode1>
<OperatorsCode2>4033</OperatorsCode2>
<OperatorsCode3 /><OperatorsCode4>esudgpgj</OperatorsCode4>
<StopName>Cysleys Farm (by request only)</StopName>
<route_stop />
<route_stop_stop /><route_stop_timetable_stop />
<stopId>6401</stopId>
</Stop>
```

Edit I get this error when trying to get the data

Could not find schema information for the element

Answer (score 0):

You will need the following tools to do what you want:

For reading the XML:
Option 1: Use the `XmlSerializer` class to load the data, if you have the c# classes that represent the XML (read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)).
Option 2: Read the XML raw using `XDocument` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.95%29.aspx))

For auto-complete box, you can look at the Silverlight Toolkit. I found the implementation to be lacking, but I know some people use it (find it [here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)). You can also implement it by yourself by using a ListBox you will show/hide on the page.

Comment: The problem with this is that it has alot of schemas so i get this error: 

Could not find schema information for the element

Comment: Sorry, it's not working. But I might not have time to implement this at the moment. Thank you anyway.